# Ingress controller is up but can't cURL externally after upgrade to kubernetes_ingress_v1 (v1 ingress) (after k8s 1.22 upgrade breaking changes)

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, cert-manager

I recently upgraded my ingress and external-dns due to the Kubernetes 1.22 upgrade. I made changes where you [can see it here](https://github.com/rivernews/iriversland2-kubernetes/pull/54/files#diff-6c23af14bc7d46344b07eb12a534dcda49210e711d4d721a87a77cb0bbd877f9).

Now the nginx controller is running on k8s w/o error, but I cannot cURL from my laptop to access the services.

What I've tried:

- `nslookup grafana.shaungc.com` or `nslookup code-server.shaungc.com` gives the result. This means the external-dns is working. I'm using Route53. I do noticed all microservice endpoint points to the same public IP address `10.245.215.152`, but I guess that's normal because I'm using `clusterIP`.
- Watch the ingress controller log (I skipped some part that seems not relevant)

```
(initially)
...
I1023 11:30:24.114812       6 controller.go:648] Replacing location "/" for server "code-server.shaungc.com" with upstream "upstream-default-backend" to use upstream "code-server-code-server-service-8003" (Ingress "code-server/code-server-ingress-resource")
I1023 11:30:24.114828       6 controller.go:648] Replacing location "/" for server "*.shaungc.com" with upstream "upstream-default-backend" to use upstream "cert-manager-dummy-svc-dummy-port" (Ingress "cert-manager/tls-wildcard-cert-ingress-resource")
I1023 11:30:24.114841       6 controller.go:648] Replacing location "/" for server "*.api.shaungc.com" with upstream "upstream-default-backend" to use upstream "cert-manager-dummy-svc-dummy-port" (Ingress "cert-manager/tls-wildcard-cert-ingress-resource")
I1023 11:30:24.114854       6 controller.go:648] Replacing location "/" for server "*.812c211c-6cbb-79e3-420e-92502524c690.shaungc.com" with upstream "upstream-default-backend" to use upstream "cert-manager-dummy-svc-dummy-port" (Ingress "cert-manager/tls-wildcard-cert-ingress-resource")
I1023 11:30:24.114874       6 controller.go:303] Obtaining information about TCP stream services from ConfigMap "kube-system/nginx-ingress-controller-ingress-nginx-tcp"
...
I1023 11:30:24.124150       6 template.go:914] empty byte size, hence it will not be set
I1023 11:30:24.198254       6 main.go:101] "successfully validated configuration, accepting" ingress="tls-wildcard-cert-ingress-resource/cert-manager"
I1023 11:30:24.203337       6 store.go:741] updating annotations information for ingress cert-manager/tls-wildcard-cert-ingress-resource
I1023 11:30:24.203620       6 main.go:187] "No default affinity found" ingress="tls-wildcard-cert-ingress-resource"
I1023 11:30:24.204116       6 store.go:775] updating references to secrets for ingress cert-manager/tls-wildcard-cert-ingress-resource
I1023 11:30:24.204362       6 backend_ssl.go:41] "Syncing Secret" name="cert-manager/wilcard-tls-ing-certificate-secret"
I1023 11:30:24.203428       6 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"cert-manager", Name:"tls-wildcard-cert-ingress-resource", UID:"a1a81692-9205-4abe-95e7-c4c0a865a49b", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1", ResourceVersion:"110423110", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'Sync' Scheduled for sync
I1023 11:30:24.204981       6 ssl.go:111] "parsing ssl certificate extensions"
I1023 11:30:24.205151       6 backend_ssl.go:145] "Configuring Secret \"cert-manager/wilcard-tls-ing-certificate-secret\" for TLS encryption ...
...
I1023 11:30:24.208957       6 endpoints.go:129] Endpoints found for Service "code-server/code-server-service": [{10.244.0.160 8003 &ObjectReference{Kind:Pod,Namespace:code-server,Name:code-server-deployment-5445c4587-64bj6,UID:b28da30d-43dd-4cf4-b365-b90e8ab0668c,APIVersion:,ResourceVersion:110407594,FieldPath:,}}]
I1023 11:30:24.209142       6 controller.go:1262] Host "grafana.shaungc.com" is listed in the TLS section but secretName is empty. Using default certificate
I1023 11:30:24.209310       6 controller.go:1262] Host "api.shaungc.com" is listed in the TLS section but secretName is empty. Using default certificate
I1023 11:30:24.209447       6 controller.go:1262] Host "appl-tracky.api.shaungc.com" is listed in the TLS section but secretName is empty. Using default certificate
I1023 11:30:24.209899       6 controller.go:1262] Host "code-server.shaungc.com" is listed in the TLS section but secretName is empty. Using default certificate
...
I1023 11:30:37.447833       6 status.go:276] "skipping update of Ingress (no change)" namespace="appl-tracky-api" ingress="appl-tracky-api-ingress-resource"
I1023 11:30:37.447842       6 status.go:276] "skipping update of Ingress (no change)" namespace="cert-manager" ingress="tls-wildcard-cert-ingress-resource"
I1023 11:30:37.447850       6 status.go:276] "skipping update of Ingress (no change)" namespace="code-server" ingress="code-server-ingress-resource"
(end of log)
```

- In the K8s dashboard I see no failed pods or resources, all green.

It previously worked. But with the 1.22 k8s upgrade and my PR change, I can't access any website/microservice on the cluster from either browser or cURL.

What else can I try to debug at this point?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the [legacy Helm chart `nginx-ingress`](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nginx-ingress) I was using, is not the same as the [kubernetes/nginx-ingress](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) chart, they are different alternatives for nginx ingress controllers - previously their development co-exist at the same time and are different solutions for nginx ingress. It's suboptimal in my opinion that the legacy Helm chart [README deprecation note](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nginx-ingress) merely point to `kubernetes/nginx-ingress`. It's not going to be a linear upgrade, they different in many default chart behaviors. I went through their version history, adapt syntax, even made it work nginx ingress runs perfectly w/o error, but still my external traffic can not reach my cluster service, not even getting the correct cluster Public IP. It just doesn't work with my use case.

The solution? Seems the [Bitnami nginx controller](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/nginx-ingress-controller) is actually the successor of the legacy helm chart. While the syntax is different - but actually just controller level configs got pull up to 1st/global level, other default behavior are pretty similar to the legacy helm and therefore it worked for my setup. In fact I was able to upgrade to latest version of Bitnami chart 9.3.18. I explained a bit more my use case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74177702/9814131). Spent my entire weekend on this!

Comment: according to old helm chart repo: "This chart is deprecated as we have moved to the upstream repo ingress-nginx". Following their link, you should have end up here: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/main/charts/ingress-nginx . While I would be surprised anything involving bitnami images would be a default/go-to/something to recommend in kubernets context, in general. And indeed, you're not deploying the official nginx-ingress controller image: https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/main/bitnami/nginx-ingress-controller/values.yaml#L55-L57

Comment: Not saying Bitnami is the goto, but easier to upgrade if you come from helm. I believe the legacy helm is actually closer to the Bitnami, e.g. both Bitnami and legacy helm have `useHostPort` configuration, whereas official repo is `hostPort.enabled`. You can compare [legacy helm](https://github.com/helm/charts/commits/master/stable/nginx-ingress) and [official](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/commits/main?after=f2ed5d17f672abf2dcda53811e0272357c0d02d4+209&branch=main&path%5B%5D=charts&path%5B%5D=ingress-nginx&qualified_name=refs%2Fheads%2Fmain) history, both exist since 2020 Nov.